# DateTimePicker control - Show "Please select a date" when no date is selected

Tags: c#, .net

How can I provide a message to the user when no date is selected?  I thought of having a Label - "Please select a date" on top of the DateTimePicker. Label will be activated when no date is selected at the start. Once the date is chosen from the calendar, the label will be set to invisible.

Is there any other way of doing my task by using "**DateTimePicker Messages**" ?

Comment: How do you define "no date selected"?  The winforms date time picker always has a date value. Is this winforms or web?

Comment: Search codeproject.com for "datetimepicker and nullable".  Lots of projects.

Comment: @JohnKoerner i m talking about about winforms.  i intend to use it excel(vsto).  no date selected would be the inintial state when the control gets rendered for the first time .

Answer (score 0):

You actually have several options for a DateTimePicker.

I've used the ***AjaxControlToolkit Calendar Extender Control*** and it works well with a feature for page field validations.

There is also the [JQuery DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker).

Or try using the validation controls in VS. :)

Comment: i m using the datetimepicker of excel.Controls namespace.